# How to set output size for ngx-webcam?

Tags: angular

I need to get the minimum size for the image captured. As far as I can test, for ngx-webcam, I can set the output image's minimum height based on the webcam display height. Is there any way I can set the min resolution of the output without affecting the webcam display?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the media options.

**In the html:**

```
<webcam *ngIf="webcamImage==null" 
[height]="380" 
[width]="500" 
[trigger]="triggerObservable"
(imageCapture)="handleImage($event)" 
[allowCameraSwitch]="allowCameraSwitch"
[switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable" 
[videoOptions]="videoOptions"<--this value -->
[imageQuality]="1"
[captureImageData]="captureImageData" 
(cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)"
(initError)="handleInitError($event)">
</webcam>
```

**And in the TS file:**

```
public get videoOptions(): MediaTrackConstraints {
//you can set ideal,min,max for width and height
        const result: MediaTrackConstraints = {width:{min:640,ideal:1920},
        height:{min:480,ideal:1080}};

    
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use the webcam tag you set the [height] and [width] of the image.
just use the same attributes when showing the output